# 14.04LTS enabling bluetooth criples wifi

Tags: bluetooth

Running 14.04 on a Pavilion dm4. Wifi works fine, but as soon as I pair a bluetooth speaker the wifi comes to a screeching halt. Anyone else have this issue? Ubuntu noob, so I am not sure where to even begin looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptop have the bluetooth and wifi in the same key, which mean that when you press the key, it will 'trigger' the 'on/off' of the bluetooth and wifi together.

I guess your wifi is on by default and bluetooth is off by default, when you press the key (F12, I presume), it turn off the wifi and turn on the bluetooth together.

Maybe you can turn on your bluetooth in the system setting instead of using keyboard hard key, go to 'System Settings' and you will able to see the bluetooth setting.